# Add shadow to image in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uikit, shadow

I have this screen with an `UIImageView` (the image is a **SF Symbol**)

[image]

The user can see this icon clearly, white on black. But - if the background is different:

[image]

It may be hard to see it.
I want to add a **black shadow** to the image so the user can see it better.

I tried looking online but all I saw is how to add shadow to the image view box, and that is not what I need. I need the shadow around the icon itself and not around the box of the image.

Any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: you say "SF Symbol" (as in a UIFont or a label) but you're talking about an image view. I'm wondering if using [a solution like the one described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062569/how-to-make-a-drop-shadow-effect-on-a-label-in-swift) might work?

Comment: I use SF Symbol as an image in my image view `UIImage(systemName: "paintbrush.pointed.fill")!`

Comment: The link you gave to an answer **does work!** thank you

Comment: glad I was able to help!

Comment: @אוריorihpt Could you attach the image you used?

Comment: @trungduc do you mean the name of the image? if so `UIImage(systemName: "paintbrush.pointed.fill")!`

Comment: @אוריorihpt Yes. In this case, Daisy the cat's answer will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```